# How to link redis rdb file with capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, redis

I am using redis with my rails application and I'm not sure how to add the redis rdb storage file to the shared directory and create a symlink on each deploy.  In my redis.conf file I have the dir set to 'dir /home/tenjack/redis-backup', but this doesn't even seem to be working and the rdb file is saved in the working directory and then gets lost on each deploy.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Redis runs independently from your rails app, right? Why would you want to add the rdb file to the shared directory and create a symlink on each deploy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this a task like this (adjust paths as needed):

```
after "deploy:update_code" do
  run "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/#{shared_dir}/default/private #{release_path}/private"
end
```